# Header for sub-headers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

In Pandas I have a table with the next columns:

`Number of words | 1 | 2 | 4 |`

...And I want to make it like the following:

`----------------|worker/node|`

`Number of words | 1 | 2 | 4 |`

So how to "create" this header for sub-features?

And how to merge empty cell (from row 1 where FeatureHeader is located) with "Index" cell in row 2?

In another words, I want to make table headers like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for add first level of `MultiIndex` by your string:

```
#if necessary convert some columns to index first
df = df.set_index(['Number of words'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Worker/node'], df.columns])
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! It's really what I need